# JMeter - No third party calls in recorded script

Tags: jmeter

I recorded a jmeter script, it has all the resources BUT the 3rd party call. If I put only main html URL and check download embedded resources with 6 parallel connection, it downloads all the resources which were downloaded when I recorded the script but also has 3rd party calls which are not there in recorded script. Why is that so? Your help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that this 3rd-party call is being filtered by the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), if you use the [Recording Template](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature/) - there are some pre-defined suggested excludes, so most probably your 3rd-party call matches one of them:

[image]

There is a possibility to filter out 3rd-party calls for the "embedded resources" as well, you can put the patterns you don't need to test i.e. in the [HTTP Requests Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

[image]